# The default value of an optional parameter must be constant - Color

Tags: dart

I am trying to set a default color to a custom Widget.

This is the code with the issue.

```
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
   ReusableCard({this.color: Color(0xFF1D1E33)});

   Color color;

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Expanded(
       child: Container(
         margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
         decoration: BoxDecoration(
           color: color,
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
         ),
       ),
     );
   }
 }
```

What is bothering me is that if I on the second line it say:

```
ReusableCard({this.color: Colors.red});
```

Then there is no issue. I have tried making creating

```
final color defaultColor = Color(0xFF1D1E33);
```

And using the defaultColor instead, but it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Colors class gives you a constant values back which is why Colors.red will work, so when you are specifying your own default then your default colour(s) also have to be constant(s)

ie. -->  const color defaultColor = Color(0xFF1D1E33);

Answer (score 1):

Just add `const` before the `Color` value:

```dart
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
   ReusableCard({this.color: const Color(0xFF1D1E33)}); // note the 'const' keyword

   Color color;

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Expanded(
       child: Container(
         margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
         decoration: BoxDecoration(
           color: color,
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
         ),
       ),
     );
   }
 }
```